# CSS Sticky Footer Odd Behavior - Overlaps Content on window resize

Tags: html, css, footer, overlap

Morning All,

I'm having a very annoying issue with a sticky footer using Ryan Fait's - however the main problem is the footer overlaps my "main" div with the content when the browser window size is reduced. when you make the browser window small enough, it eventually disappears. I just want to stop it from overlapping the content, so as I make the window smaller, the footer sticks to the bottom of the page until it gets near the "main" div, then it should go out of view (creating a scroll bar for the page).

I've searched for and tried more than a dozen fixes via google to no avail (I have a feeling it's probably a piece of bad code on my behalf causing an issue) - I'm recently getting back into the swing of things with web design.

Enough of my talking anyway, see for yourself here: http://www.steviespittle.com/recruitment/design3/index.php

P.s. it's not optimized for I.E 7/8 at all - another issue I'm struggling with as I'm not familiar with cross-browser compatibility.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Stevie

Comment: Hi, Sorry If I didn't explain myself well enough, the main problem is the footer overlaps my "main" div with the content when the browser window size is reduced. when you make the browser window small enough, it eventually disappears. I just want to stop it from overlapping the content, so as I make the window smaller, the footer sticks to the bottom of the page until it gets near the "main" div, then it should go out of view (creating a scroll bar for the page).

Comment: Have you tried min widths and heights for the main div? If you want the difference to disappear, you may need css media queries.

Comment: I found an alternative sticky footer that does what I need at the following link - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Thanks for your suggestion anyway :)